# Até que ponto tentar prever o futuro ao projetar uma aplicação?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, engenharia-de-software, projeto-de-software, gerenciamento-de-projetos, requisitos

Até que ponto podemos ou devemos tentar prever o futuro ao projetar uma aplicação? Seja arquiteturalmente, seja no design.

O que torna um design robusto frente a mudanças sem ser contudo excessivamente planejado?

É um caso especial de YAGNI, que na sua forma mais radical (e acredito que [original](http://wiki.c2.com/?YouArentGonnaNeedIt)) se traduz em:

*"Sempre implemente as coisas quando **realmente** precisar delas, não quando você apenas **prever** que precisa delas."*

Por outro lado, Alistair Cockburn diz:

> Pelo visto não conseguimos discutir a qualidade de um "design" até que tenhamos votado em um futuro! Eca (*E-e-yuck*).
>
> Podemos avaliar uma solução com relação a suas metas de espaço e desempenho (note que para fazer isso, precisamos ter uma meta de espaço e desempenho!). Podemos conversar sobre quão "agradável" um design parece ser, quão "natural". Mas não podemos falar sobre quão robusto ele é sem eleger um futuro para suportar. Diferentes futuros dão origem a diferentes designs otimizados (assim como diferentes metas dão origem a diferentes compromissos de espaço e tempo).

[Problema de design de uma máquina de café, parte 2](https://web.archive.org/web/20170608075902/http://alistair.cockburn.us/Coffee+machine+design+problem%2c+part+2) ([parte 1 aqui](https://web.archive.org/web/20170627053310/http://alistair.cockburn.us/Coffee+machine+design+problem%2c+part+1), é um exercício de design orientado a objetos).

Comment: Resolva os problemas que você tem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A parte mais complicada de tudo eu creio que seja realmente essa. Independente da arquitetura e stack que vc escolhe, sempre irá cair nesse dilema.

Humildemente vou tentar reponder isso na minha perspectiva de gerente de projetos a qual me coloca diariamente a frente de precificação e design das aplicações.

Eu primeiramente me perguntaria o seguinte antes de começar:

**Isto trata-se de um processo circunscrito, ou seja, temos a visão atual do processo do início ao fim? Eu consigo colocar isso em um project (gantt chart) e orçar isso de forma organizada?**

Se sim, nesse caso basta entendermos os processos envolvidos, e desenvolver em ordem cronológica na qual os clientes estão envolvidos para seguir com o desenvolvimento.

Nesse caso, poucas conversas com os clientes resolvem. Geralmente no máximo 3 conversas.

Geralmente quebramos em "must haves", "nice to haves" e "good to haves". Depois que acabar os "must haves" se sobrar tempo ai vamos para os outros (diga-se de passagem o que geralmente nunca acontece).

Nessa situação sabe-se antecipadamente (de forma aproximada) o "quanto custa" e "quando fica pronto".

**Caso não trate-se de algo que já funciona atualmente e estejamos falando de alguma "ruptura", ou seja, um novo produto ou serviço, no qual não existe?**

Nesse caso o modelo de gestão e desenvolvimento deve ser orientado a Sprints. Temos uma vaga idéia de quanto vai custar e de nenhuma idéia de quando fica pronto.

Nessa situação temos um universo no qual a coisa poderá NUNCA acabar pois sempre haverá melhora contínua.

Nesse caso eu diria que o "bolso" do cliente ou do dono da coisa vai dizer até aonde esse aprimoramento contínuo seguirá.

Será um MVP? Será um app de milhões investidos?

O quanto o jogo de desenvolvimento irá durar estará diretamente ligado a quantia ou tempo de quem quer investir na coisa.

**Concluindo**

Como mencionado: "*diferentes metas dão origem a diferentes compromissos de espaço e tempo*".

Isso resume tudo. Existem situações em que o design está bem claro e determinado. O usuário precisa de um sistema de emissão de NFE integrado com SAP. Você não precisa de um design muito arrojado para atendê-lo. Se for web, um bootstrap, coreUI com um backend simples pode resolver. Você não vai fazer um app com backend em microservices ou utilizar um designer conceituado para fazer o formulário. Não há muito além do que foi passado a ser enxergado.

O cliente quer um aplicativo para estimar a cotação do dólar nos próximos 20 dias analisando noticias na web e determinadas fontes. Isso pode tender ao infinito em desenvolvimento.

Tudo vai do cenário e eu diria que por experiência, pelo tamanho do investimento disponível.

Comment: Acho que é bem por aí. Quando fiz a pergunta tinha uma visão mais centralizada na autonomia do projetista/arquiteto, quando na verdade é preciso de feedback do cliente ou mesmo oferecer as alternativas que embasem uma decisão. Boa resposta.